# Invisible object

Tags: objects, edit-mode

As I started to add materials (glossy) to my objects, at one point in that process I realized I couldn't see one of my objects.

It was still "there" because all that remained was a grey dot (which turned orange when the shape was selected) presumably at its center of mass. I assume this is the 3D manipulator?

When i clicked it, it let me move this invisible object and scale it etc, but I couldn't see it in object mode, edit mode, rendered, wireframe, sculpting. You get the idea...

I need this fixed to continue with my model. Also, I'm new to blender.

Thanks

Pics:
(I named the invisible object invisible)

[image: The grey dot]

[image: It still recognizes it as an object?]

Comment: It might be an object with a single vertex that you accidentally created. Why don't you just delete it, or back-step (Ctrl-Z) to get back to where it wasn't like that? .

Comment: @AnthonyForwood I dont think I accidentally created it because I renamed it from previously something like "cylinder 001". However at the top of my screen it tells me I have 0 vertices etc so maybe I might have deleted it?? But if i deleted it why would blender still count it as an object.

Comment: Blender still counts an object with zero vertices an object when you delete all the vertices in edit mode. Upon return to object mode it still thinks it is an object because you didn't "delete" it.

Comment: Unfortunately you cropped the picture on your question leaving out the clues that would help us determine what is wrong. Are you in edit or object mode? is the visibility (eye) icon disabled?. Other thing that might have happened is that the geometry is hidden in edit mode. Try Alt H

Comment: @cegaton wouldn't it be impossible for him to select the object if he enabled restrict viewport visiblity?

Comment: @SammySwanson In the outliner Visibility and selectability are different options. There you can select an invisible object

Comment: You should upload your file.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys. Like I said i tried object and edit mode, and i forgot to mention I tried alt H. No big deal, it wasn't too complicated to do again. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this an official answer:

## Why is it there?

Blender still counts an object with zero vertices an object when you delete all the vertices in edit mode. Upon return to object mode it still thinks it is an object because you didn't "delete" it.

## How do I fix it?

A. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> 

B. Start over, hit <kbd>X</kbd> then <kbd>D</kbd> to delete your zero vertex object